# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Redistributable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, download, servicepacks

Does anyone know where to download the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Redistributable?

I sure would like to have it so I don't have to download the service pack for every install.

Comment: Either clarify our question or search MSDN.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this sucks.

Comment: Do you mean the Visual C++ redistributable package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=27673c47-b3b5-4c67-bd99-84e525b5ce61&displaylang=en) - Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (iso)?

Comment: You have sha1 on that ISO by chance? Microsoft didn't list it on their download page...

Comment: Found it, sha1 for VS2008SP1ENUX1512962.iso: 2459232f67b38594de192778020145dcd0b0df9f

Answer (score 3):

You can get Visual Studio 2008 SP1 ISO here - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=27673c47-b3b5-4c67-bd99-84e525b5ce61&displaylang=en

It is 831.3 MB

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en

Answer (score -1):

Tried [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en)?

Comment: Umm that's a link to "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package". Going to go out on a limb and say that might not be the patch he is looking for.

Comment: This is not VS 2008 SP1, this is VC++ 2008 SP1.